# Getting both AMD Catalyst and Touchpad to work on Samsung Laptop(NP730U3E)

Tags: touchpad, synaptic, radeon, amd, fglrx

I have a Samsung NP730U3E Laptop, and have huge problems finding a good Linux installation for it.

I've tried several distributions, but all have had some major draw back:

- Ubuntu and UbuntuGnome (12.04 & 13.10) worked like a charm until I tried to install [Amd Catalyst](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux%20x86_64#) to get the AMD Radeon HD 8570M graphics card to work. At first it seemed like everything was fine, but on the first reboot everything crashed. It just went black and froze. I could get into the terminal via Ctrl+Alt+F2, but all graphical interfaces seemed dead.
- On Debian 7.4 on the other hand the graphics drivers worked like a charm! Stable and working! Unfortunately my [touch pad didn't work](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2133395&page=3#post_12691159), so that rendered it useless.
- Fedora 20 works great with the synaptics drivers for the touch pad, but Catalyst doesn't seem to install (have tried both 13.12 and 14.3 Beta drivers). It just outputs:

> One or more tools required for installation cannot be found on the system.
>
> Install the required tools before installing the fglrx driver. Optionally, run the installer with --force option to install without the tools. Forcing install will disable AMD hardware acceleration and may make your system unstable. Not recommended.
>
> See /usr/share/ati/fglrx-install.log for more details.

The `/usr/share/ati/fglrx-install.log` looks as follows:

> Supported adapter detected.
>   Check if system has the tools required for installation.
>   fglrx installation requires that the system have kernel headers for 3.7 release.  /lib/modules/3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64/build/include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h cannot be found on this system.
>   One or more tools required for installation cannot be found on the system. Install the required tools before installing the fglrx driver.
>   Optionally, run the installer with --force option to install without the tools.
>   Forcing install will disable AMD hardware acceleration and may make your system unstable. Not recommended.

Any ideas on how to get both the graphics drivers and touch pad to work?

Comment: Did you install the required kernel headers?

Comment: Nope, I didn't know how to do that. But it works for me on Ubuntu 14.04 now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The [AMD Catalyst™ 14.4 Proprietary Linux x86 Display Driver](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux%20x86_64) works great on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and the touchpad works great on it too.

Comment: Can I get some feedback on why my answer deserved to be down voted?